# Android - List of apps playing sound

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a project on Android Xamarin and I want to get the list of programs that are playing sound. I use the code below, but to no avail.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.WithAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.InternalContentUri, "1");
intent.SetData(uri);
intent.SetType("audio/*");
IList<ResolveInfo> apps = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
foreach (ResolveInfo rInfo in apps)
{

}
```

Is there another alternative? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with shared code and **it works** in my physical device , you should **notice** whether the device contains the playing sound apps. If not sure simulator device installed audio apps better use a physical device to test that .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.WithAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.InternalContentUri, "1");
intent.SetData(uri);
intent.SetType("audio/*");
IList<ResolveInfo> apps = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
foreach (ResolveInfo rInfo in apps)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---" + rInfo);
}
```

The Console log is :

```
03-24 14:19:40.117 I/mono-stdout( 1940): ---ResolveInfo{9002d72 cn.kuwo.player/.activities.EntryActivity m=0x608000}
03-24 14:19:40.119 I/mono-stdout( 1940): ---ResolveInfo{b1845c3 com.baidu.searchbox/.music.SearchMusicActivity m=0x608000}
03-24 14:19:40.119 I/mono-stdout( 1940): ---ResolveInfo{6694e40 com.qiyi.video/org.iqiyi.video.activity.PlayerActivity m=0x608000}
03-24 14:19:40.119 I/mono-stdout( 1940): ---ResolveInfo{62e0179 com.tencent.mobileqq/.activity.JumpActivity m=0x608000}
```

Comment: I'm testing on a physical device and Android 7.1.
Did you ask for permission for the device?

Comment: @DiegoJota I'm not asking for permission when running , my device is Android 10 . Just allow the default permission when installing application .And my project is a new created Xamarin Android Projecr , only adding shared code in my Button Method .